# Can Duende IdentityServer v6 be used in a .Net Framework Application?

Tags: identityserver3, duende-identity-server

We are reviewing our our applications which use IdentityServer now it has rebranded to Duende become a subscription model and have come across a forgotten application which consists of a number of .Net Framework projects, one of which references the dll's IdentityServer3 and IdentityServer3.WsFederation.

If we want to be using a supportable we need to upgrade to IdentityServer v6 but given that this is a .Net 6 application, the only route I can see to this is to upgrade all the projects in the solution to be .Net 6 also.

Is there a supported .Net Framework compatible version of IdentityServer?

If not is there a trick I am missing which means I don't have to upgrade the entire solution to .Net Core and maybe limit it to just the one project that references these two dll's?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, Duende IdentityServer v6 is built on .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET Core 3.1, which are not compatible with .NET Framework.

.NET Standard is a set of APIs that are available on multiple .NET platforms, including .NET Core and .NET Framework. However, .NET Standard 2.1 is not supported by .NET Framework, which means that any library or application that targets .NET Standard 2.1 can only be used on platforms that support it, such as .NET Core 3.1 or later.

Therefore, if you want to use Duende IdentityServer v6, you will need to migrate your application to .NET Core 3.1 or later, or consider using an earlier version of Duende IdentityServer that is compatible with .NET Framework.

It's worth noting that Microsoft has announced that .NET Framework will reach end of support on June 30, 2024, so if you do decide to migrate to .NET Core, you will be ensuring that your application remains supported and secure in the long term.